# Getting the x_values from XY Scatter plot in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to use python-pptx to extract XY scatter data for special cases where the reference excel sheet is not present and my existing VBA code fails to read the data. I can get all the y_values but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the `x_values`. From the documentation, I understand XY Scatter doesn't have "categories" like the other plots. However, I don't see any method or object in the chart or `chart.plots[0]` that will give me access to the `x_values`. I only see `"categories"` and of course, it is empty for XY Scatter.

```
    def get_chart_data():
    for sld in prs.slides:
        for shape in sld.shapes:
            if shape.has_chart:
                chart = shape.chart
                series_data=[]
                for series in chart.series:
                    y_val = []
                    for value in series.values:
                        y_val.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API support for this yet, so if you want it bad enough you'll have to dive down to `lxml` level calls to get it.

An example of the XML for an XY-Scatter chart is show in this `python-pptx` analysis document: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/cht-xy-chart.html#xml-specimen. Here's a partial snippet:

```xml
<c:chart>
    <c:scatterChart>
      <c:ser>
        ...
        <c:xVal>
          <c:numRef>
            <c:f>Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7</c:f>
            <c:numCache>
              <c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode>
              <c:ptCount val="6"/>
              <c:pt idx="0">
                <c:v>0.7</c:v>
              </c:pt>
              <c:pt idx="1">
                <c:v>1.8</c:v>
              </c:pt>
              <c:pt idx="2">
                <c:v>2.6</c:v>
              </c:pt>
            </c:numCache>
          </c:numRef>
        </c:xVal>
        <c:yVal>
          <c:numRef>
            <c:f>Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7</c:f>
            <c:numCache>
              <c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode>
              <c:ptCount val="6"/>
              <c:pt idx="0">
                <c:v>2.7</c:v>
              </c:pt>
              <c:pt idx="1">
                <c:v>3.2</c:v>
              </c:pt>
              <c:pt idx="2">
                <c:v>0.8</c:v>
              </c:pt>
            </c:numCache>
          </c:numRef>
        </c:yVal>
      </c:ser>
      ...
    <c:scatterChart>
    ...
<c:chart>
```

The point data is divided between the `c:xVal` element and `c:yVal` element. You can use `XPath` and `lxml.etree._Element` calls to get it:

```py
for series in chart.series:
    ser = series._ser
    x_pts = ser.xpath(".//c:xVal//c:pt")
    for pt in x_pts:
        print("pt.idx == %s", pt.get("idx"))
        str_value = pt.xpath("./c:v")[0].text
        value = float(str_value)
        print("value == %s" % value)
```

You'd need to extend this general approach to also get Y-values, match up into (x, y) pairs based on matching `idx` (don't rely on document order), probably discarding any that don't form full sets; I vaguely remember that can happen.

Comment: I confirmed this does works. Also after I posted the questions I did more research and found @scanny answer from 1yr ago. [link](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/393) Would the method in the link be a better way to get the xVal's and yVal's.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the final code I have base on the answer from @scanny.
My goal with this was to be able to loop through Power Point slides and extract data from XY Scatter plots that no longer had the linked excel sheet.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.series import XySeries
import numpy as np

def get_chart_data(prs):
    for sld in prs.slides:
        for shape in sld.shapes:
            if shape.has_chart:
                chart = shape.chart
                series_data = {}
                series_data[shape.name] = {}
                if isinstance(chart.series[0], XySeries): #check if XY Series
                    for series in chart.series:
                        x_values, y_values = read_xy(series)

                        #create dictionary with Chart name and series names
                        series_data[shape.name][series.name] = np.array([x_values, y_values])
                    for c in series_data.keys(): #get chart keys
                        for s in series_data[c].keys(): # get series keys
                            data_final = series_data[c][s].T #retrieve XY data for given chart and series
                            np.savetxt(f'{shape.name}_{s}.csv', data_final, delimiter=',')

def read_xy(series):
    xVal = {}
    yVal = {}
    ser = series._ser
    x_pts = ser.xpath(".//c:xVal//c:pt") # get all xVals from xml with xpath query
    y_pts = ser.xpath(".//c:yVal//c:pt") # get all yVals from xml with xpath query
    for i in range(len(x_pts)): #loop through all xVals
        x_value = get_pt_val(x_pts[i]) #call function to get each x value
        y_value = get_pt_val(y_pts[i]) #call function to get each y value
        xVal[x_pts[i].idx] = x_value #store x value in dictionary
        yVal[y_pts[i].idx] = y_value # store y value in dictionary

    # in case x & y idx don't have matching pairs return keys that are common to both x & y
    key = set.intersection(*tuple(set(d.keys()) for d in [xVal, yVal]))
    xVal = [xVal[x] for x in key] #create xVal list
    yVal = [yVal[x] for x in key] #create yVal list
    return xVal, yVal

def get_pt_val(pt):
    str_value = pt.xpath("./c:v")[0].text #retrieve point value
    value = float(str_value)
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prs = Presentation('Test.pptx')
    get_chart_data(prs)
```